# typedef class: Unknown type name 'MyType'; did you mean 'MyType_t'?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a cpp header file with a construct like this:

```
typedef class MyType_t {

//...

public:
    void    method();

} MyType;
```

I'm trying to use it from a .mm file like this:

```
MyType.method();
```

And this causes compiler error "Unknown type name 'MyType'; did you mean 'MyType_t'?"

The compiler seem to be able to understand "MyType_t", but "MyType" seems not to be supported. I known only very basic c++ and don't know exactly what this construct is for. I just downloaded this code and have to call it from objective-c.

Comment: What do you want MyType to be, a variable or the name of a type? One the one hand what you have above is the name of a type, and the name you gave it 'MyType' suggests you want it to be the name of a type. But you use it like it's a variable `MyType.method();`. So can't really answer the question unless you say what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to run working code downloaded from internet in objective c ^.^ I don't understand yet why the author made it using typedef MyType_t and MyType. For now the question is answered, from a practical point of view at least.

Comment: Well if I had to guess I would say delete the word typedef, but I think you and me are both guessing. Seeing more of the code might help. Do you trust code from the internet when a) you don't understand it and b) it doesn't compile. Seems like shaky foundations for whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not calling the constructor before using `MyType`

So adding this

```
MyType MyType_t(parameter);
```

solved it.

Comment: I'd just say that using a typedef with a name that is different from the class tag is just pointless and is going to create confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Neither should work.

Did you mean:

```
class MyType_t {

//...

public:
    void    method();

} MyType;
```

The `typedef` declares a new type called `MyType` identical to `MyType_t`. The syntax above declares a variable `MyType` of type `MyType_t`.

Comment: The class has no constructors. Removing `typedef` causes now compiler error in the header file: No matching constructor for initialization of 'class MyType_t'. I know that adding the constructor could help, but the author of this code seems to had something different in mind...

Comment: @Ixx a class can't have no constructors. A default one is generated by the compiler in the absence of user-defined constructors.

Comment: Ok. BTW there is even a constructor... blind today. But why I get the compiler error?

Comment: @Ixx it probably doesn't match the signature of the constructor.

Comment: +1 For pointing me in the right direction, but it didn't answer directly the problem.